# Mirantis Openstack Fuel unable to provision nodes with VIRT role

Tags: openstack

I need to reproduce MOS 9.2 installation.
So, previously MOS 9.2 was installed on 7 baremetal servers with such roles:

2 - compute

3 - virt (Looks like 3 controllers were deployed as a virtuals)

2 - ceph

I've successfully installed fuel master, updated it to 9.2, created environment and now I need to add nodes with appropriate roles, but when I'm trying to assign role VIRT to 3 physical servers I'm getting an error:

```
# fuel2 env add nodes -e 6 -n 9 -r virt
400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://MYIP:8000/api/v1/clusters  /6/assigment/ (Role 'virt' restrictions mismatch: )
```

When I'm trying to define 3 nodes:

```
# fuel2 env add nodes -e 6 -n 9,10,11 -r virt
fuel2 env add nodes: error: argument -n/--nodes: invalid int value: '9,10,11'
```

Also I didn't find role 'virt' in Fuel web UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by editing /etc/nailgun/settings.yaml:

```
FEATURE_GROUPS:
  - "advanced"
```